# How to fix this foundation crack in the backyard

Tags: foundation

First time homeowner, just saw that the foundation is slightly cracked. Is this evidence of movement?

I see thin hairline cracks extending from here for about 2 inches horizontally…

If yes how do I fix it? How much time do I have?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: what is inside of the wall?   We need a picture from the other side.   Unless a crack is really bad and obvious - yours isn't - then it is more important to see inside.   Also is there any issue below grade?

Comment: There are 2 kinds of concrete the kind that is cracked and the kind that will crack. there should be rebar in the foundation and that crack doesn't look bad. If you live in an area that freezes it would be a good idea to seal it so water is kept out and freezing won’t create a problem. It would be a good idea to seal it even if you are not in a freeze area. A good quality urethane calk will seal it and then keep an eye on it in 5 -10 years you might need to replace the calk but without any info on the age you may only have 50 years but nothing to worry about.

Comment: Are you sure that is concrete and not something like stucco over the top?  It looks like there are trowel lines on it which makes me think some sort of finish was put over the wall.

Answer (score 1):

Foundation settlement will produce wide diagonal crack(s) at the foundation beam-column joint and tilted from the bottom (widest) towards the top (narrower). There may also be a few finer, shorter cracks in the mid-span with both vertically and slightly tilted orientations.

Your cracks were caused by drying shrinkage during the time the concrete was starting to set. Although the cracks have no structural significance, you should repair them by widening the cracks to get rid of the loose material along the cracks, then seal them with cement-based mortar/sealant.

Answer (score 0):

Bad foundations cracks are vertical and extend through the foundation into the brickwaork.

A small horizontal crack is not something to worry about.  in your photo the only crack I see is associated with a blemish in the cement render applied to the surface of the foundation.

It could still warrant investigation, tap around it lightly and if it sounds hollow investigate further there may be rusting reinforcement behind it (but I would expect to see staining if that were the case).

Comment: Thank you, for your response, I can put in a penny in the crack, does that indicate it is more than a blemish? Thanks!

Comment: If it is that big, perhaps I'm not seeing it. please edit you photo to show the location of the crack (or draw on the wall with chalk or charcoal and take another photo)

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/Ba2ijib.jpg
the crack marked: https://i.imgur.com/2uSpe1V.jpg

Comment: Also tapped around it, it doesn't feel hollow...

Comment: it looks like cosmetic surface damage, but if it's not "drummy" it may go deeper. it does not seem to be a structural crack.